# Como criar uma URL amigável

Tags: php, url, link

Estou fazendo um site de guia comercial, porém quando usuário visualiza os detalhes dessa empresa a URL aparece de seguinte forma:

```
www.nomedomeusite/detalhes.php?id_empresa=24
```

O `id_empresa=24` estou pegando via `$_GET['id_empresa'];`.

Gostaria de saber se tem como ser:

```
www.nomedomeusite/id_da_empresa/nome_da_empresa.html
```

Esse seria o link para acessar:

```
<a href="detalhes.php?id_empresa=<?php echo $id_empresa; ?>"><button  type="button">ver detalhes</button></a>
```

Comment: Tem https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 0):

Use uma variável de sessão como

```
$_SESSION['id_empresa']
```

ou use um form com metodo POST para não aparecer no site

```
<form action="www.nomedomeusite" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" value="24" name="id_empresa">
  <input type="submit" name="ver detalhes">
</form>
```

no seu link vc busca o id assim

```
$_POST['id_empresa'];
```

espero ter ajudado